# Julia Jump : Getting all feasible solutions to mip

Tags: optimization, julia, mixed-integer-programming, julia-jump

I would like to have instead of only the vector of optimal solution to a mip , all the feasible (suboptimal) vectors.
I found some old questions here, but I am not sure how they work.

First of all, is there any new library tool/way to do that automatically ?
I tried this but, it did nothing:

```
if termination_status(m) == MOI.FEASIBLE_POINT
    println(x)
end
optimize!(m);
```

If not, what's the easiest way?
I thought of scanning the optimal solution till I find the first non -zero decision variable, then constraint this variable to be zero and solving the model again.

```
for i in 1:active_variables
    if value.(z[i])==1
        @constraint(m, x[i] == 0)
        break
    end
end

optimize!(m);
```

But I see this problem with this method** :

1. Ιf I constraint x[i] to be zero, in the next step I will want maybe to drop again this constraint? This comes down to whether there can exist two(or more) different solutions in which `x[i]==1`

---

Comment: Do you want to see all the suboptimal solutions that solver "looks at" while moving around the simplex? Or you want to enumerate all possible values that meet the constraints regardless of goal function and the solution process?

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel I want both I guess,.. but the second one is more general

Comment: I see in the OP, you already had this idea of recursive solving. It should work. Note, you can cut the solution space using several variables into smaller and smaller parts (and backtrack to traverse whole tree of subspaces). *Recursion* is key (to get the exponential blow-up which is needed in these counting problems of exponential nature)

Comment: @DanGetz somehow it is ignored.. I wrote this code and prints nothing .. I added this after the first time I called ```optimize();```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an example of all-solution finder for a boolean problem. Such problems are easier to handle since the solution space is easily enumerated (even though it can still grow exponentially big).

First, let's get the packages and define the sample problem:

```
using Random, JuMP, HiGHS, MathOptInterface

function example_knapsack()
    profit = [5, 3, 2, 7, 4]
    weight = [2, 8, 4, 2, 5]
    capacity = 10
    minprofit = 10
    model = Model(HiGHS.Optimizer)
    set_silent(model)
    @variable(model, x[1:5], Bin)
    @objective(model, FEASIBILITY_SENSE, 0)
    @constraint(model, weight' * x <= capacity)
    @constraint(model, profit' * x >= minprofit)
    return model
end
```

(it is a knapsack problem from the JuMP docs).

Next, we use recursion to explore the tree of all possible solutions. The tree does not go down branches with no solution (so the running time is not always exponential):

```
function findallsol(model, x)
    perm = shuffle(1:length(x))
    res = Vector{Float64}[]
    _findallsol!(res, model, x, perm, 0)
    return res
end

function _findallsol!(res, model, x, perm, depth)
    n = length(x)
    depth > n && return
    optimize!(model)
    if termination_status(model) == MathOptInterface.OPTIMAL
        if depth == n
            push!(res, value.(x))
            return
        else
            idx = perm[depth+1]
            v = value(x[idx])
            newcon = @constraint(model, x[idx] == v)
            _findallsol!(res, model, x, perm, depth + 1)
            delete(model, newcon)
            newcon = @constraint(model, x[idx] == 1 - v)
            _findallsol!(res, model, x, perm, depth + 1)
            delete(model, newcon)
        end
    end
    return
end
```

Now we can:

```
julia> m = example_knapsack()
A JuMP Model
Maximization problem with:
Variables: 5
...
Names registered in the model: x

julia> res = findallsol(m, m.obj_dict[:x])
5-element Vector{Vector{Float64}}:
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
 [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
 [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
```

And we get a vector with all the solutions.

If the problem in question is a boolean problem, this method might be used, as is. In case it has non-boolean variables, the recursion will have to split the feasible space in some even fashion. For example, choosing a variable and cutting its domain in half, and recursing to each half with a smaller domain on this variable (to ensure termination).

P.S. This is not the optimal method. This problem has been well studied. Possible terms to search for are 'model counting' (especially in the boolean domain).

(UPDATE: Changed objective to use FEASIBLE)

Comment: I marking this as the most useful since I got to install highs easily while I had trouble with cplex. Instead of all optimal solutions I want all the feasible ones.. So maybe I need to change ``` if termination_status(model) == MathOptInterface.OPTIMAL``` to something else?

Comment: @tonythestark You are right, the objective function is not needed, and JuMP allows setting the objective `sense` to `FEASIBILITY_SENSE` to achieve this. [Updating answer to include it]

Comment: would be really helpful If you show me how to code this

Comment: @tonythestark Sure. Changing the answer to reflect it (actually did it earlier). Note the `@objective` definition in the problem.

Answer (score 3):

JuMP supports returning multiple solutions.

Documentation: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/manual/solutions/#Multiple-solutions

The workflow is something like:

```
using JuMP
model = Model()
@variable(model, x[1:10] >= 0)
# ... other constraints ...
optimize!(model)

if termination_status(model) != OPTIMAL
    error("The model was not solved correctly.")
end

an_optimal_solution = value.(x; result = 1)
optimal_objective = objective_value(model; result = 1)
for i in 2:result_count(model)
    @assert has_values(model; result = i)
    println("Solution $(i) = ", value.(x; result = i))
    obj = objective_value(model; result = i)
    println("Objective $(i) = ", obj)
    if isapprox(obj, optimal_objective; atol = 1e-8)
        print("Solution $(i) is also optimal!")
    end
end
```

But you need a solver that supports returning multiple solutions, and to configure the right solver-specific options.

See this blog post: https://jump.dev/tutorials/2021/11/02/tutorial-multi-jdf/

Comment: I tried exaclty that but it seems like I was never getting into the for loop (I actually printed result_count and it was 1) so maybe I chose wrong solver?

Comment: You'll need to choose Gurobi or CPLEX and set their options appropriately (see blog post). Most solvers do not support returning multiple solutions.